# How to turn off "Add file to git" in Intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When I create a new class file,

even though I turn off this option ***"When files are created: Do not add"***,

[image]

always "Add file to git" notification harass me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for but let me try.

Settings marked with a console icon are only applied to the current project([Read this article](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configure-project-settings.html)). So when you create a new project (or open a new project), it defaults to "Ask". However, you can change that in `File -> New Projects Setup -> Settings for New Projects...` which will open the same settings window for you but these settings will be applied by default if you create/open new projects in Intellij. Setting this to "Do not add" should be enough to never get the "Add file to git" pop-up window again.

Comment: I think because this project is a pre-made one